# Is there a faster way to retrieve data from a table?

Tags: vb.net

**I have used this loop to display Data that graph using the Google Chart**

The problem is that the graph contains a lot of data and it takes a long time to be made loaning
The question is whether there is a faster way to pass the data base?

```
     dRow As Data.DataRow In xdata.Rows
                        If j = 0 Then
                            TempDate = Format(CDate(dRow.Item(0)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            MyXML += "[new Date(" & TempDate.Year & "," &    TempDate.Month - 1 & ")" 
                            j += 1
                        Else
                            TempDate = Format(CDate(dRow.Item(0)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            MyXML += ",[new Date(" & TempDate.Year & "," & TempDate.Month - 1 & ")"
                            j += 1
                        End If
                        For colIdx As Byte = 1 To xdata.Columns.Count - 1
                            If colIdx > 0 Then
                                If (dRow.Item(colIdx)).ToString <> Nothing Then
                                    MyXML += "," & (dRow.Item(colIdx)).ToString
                                Else
                                    MyXML += "," & "0"
                                End If
                            End If 

`
```

Comment: How many rows in xdata?

Comment: It depends on what you choose to display a graph, can reach thousands

Comment: have you measured the time to load the data from database and then measuring the rendering? Thousands of record should not stress any decent database. Which do you use and which driver?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Does loading the data from your database take so long or is it the loop you which is slow? This is importart and you have to measure it.

Comment: Loop takes a lot of time because it goes on all the lines and there are a lot of lines

Comment: What is this `MyXML` what you are creating?

Comment: This string produces a graph using the Google Chart data to the table

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `StringBuilder` if you are going to be concatenating hundreds of strings. .NET strings are immutable which means each time they change, a new object has to be created.

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For dRow As Data.DataRow In xdata.Rows
    If j = 0 Then
        TempDate = Format(CDate(dRow.Item(0)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        sb.Append("[new Date(" & TempDate.Year & "," &    TempDate.Month - 1 & ")")
        j += 1
    Else
        TempDate = Format(CDate(dRow.Item(0)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        sb.Append(",[new Date(" & TempDate.Year & "," & TempDate.Month - 1 & ")")
        j += 1
    End If
    For colIdx As Byte = 1 To xdata.Columns.Count - 1
        If colIdx > 0 Then
            If (dRow.Item(colIdx)).ToString <> Nothing Then
                sb.Append("," & (dRow.Item(colIdx)).ToString)
            Else
                sb.Append("," & "0")
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

And when you're done parsing the data:

```
Return sb.ToString
```

Comment: The method must return a normal string that is transmitted text box

Comment: You can use StringBuilder.ToString for that. You just use the StringBuilder to build the actual string which should speed up your loop considerably. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Added an example to my answer, let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Additionally he can omit formatting the dates. He don´t use the format at all. Also formatting should be done by the client service thus Google Chart.